# Writing flatten method in Scheme

Tags: scheme

I have been working on the following function flatten and so far have it working for just lists. I was wondering if someone could provide me with some insight on how to get it work with pairs? For example (flatten '(a .a)) would return (a a). Thanks.

```
(define (flatten list)
   (cond ((null? list) null)
         ((list? (car list)) (append (flatten (car list)) (flatten (cdr list))))
         (else
          (cons (car list) (flatten (cdr list))))))
```

Comment: Flattening `(a . a)` into `(a a)` just seems wrong, since that really introduces an extra level, not decrease it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's one option:

```
(define (flatten x)
  (cond ((null? x) '())
        ((pair? x) (append (flatten (car x)) (flatten (cdr x))))
        (else (list x))))
```

Answer (score 4):

This does what you want, without requiring append, making it o(n). I walks the list as a tree. Some schemes might throw a stack overflow error if the list is too deeply nested. In guile this is not the case.

I claim no copyright for this code.

```
(define (flatten lst)
  (let loop ((lst lst) (acc '()))
    (cond
     ((null? lst) acc)
     ((pair? lst) (loop (car lst) (loop (cdr lst) acc)))
     (else (cons lst acc)))))
```

Comment: That's a real brain twister. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
(define (flatten l)
  (cond
    [(empty? l) empty]
    [(list? l)
     (append (flatten (first l))
             (flatten (rest l)))]
    [else (list l)]))
```