# Racket List elements within a list

Tags: list, racket

I have something that returns a list of elements, but sometimes the list of elements are also lists of elements.

Example of this would be:

```
(1 2 3 (4 5) (6 7 (8)))
```

I can't seem to write a function that just converts it into list with just the elements.

```
(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8)
```

Comment: The procedure you're describing is usually called `flatten`. It's part of Racket, and has been discussed [before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8387583/writing-flatten-method-in-scheme) in Stack Overflow.

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer, and then accept it, so that people know it has been solved.

Comment: I moved the answer you came up with to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer that the original poster came up with, for the benefit of anyone happening upon this question:

```
(define (test expresssion)
   (cond ((empty? expresssion) null)
         ((not (list? expresssion)) (list expresssion))
         (else (append (test (first expresssion))
                       (test (rest expresssion))))))

(test '(A (B (C) D) A)) ; => '(A B C D A)
```