# Scheme (Pretty Big) defining a "level" funciton

Tags: scheme, lambda

I am trying to define a function in Scheme, using Pretty Big language (in Dr. Racket) that will take a list and convert all the 'atoms' to top-level elements. For example, if given:

```
(level '(a b (c d) (e f (g 4 h))))
;=> (a b c d e f g 4 h)
```

Here is the code I have so far:

```
;;level -takes list and returns list w/all elements as top-level
(define level
  (lambda (L)
    (cond ((null? L) L)
          ((not( pair? L)) L)
          (else (append (level(car L)) (level(cdr L)))))))
```

My error is as follows:

```
append: contract violation
  expected: list?
  given: d
```

Can anyone help me troubleshoot this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For more about how to implement `flatten` (which is what this kind of function is usually called), have a look at

- [Writing flatten method in Scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8387583/1281433)

As to your specific error, `append` expects all (it can usually take more than two) of its arguments to be lists.  E.g.,

```
> (append '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6))
;=> (1 2 3 4 5 6)
> (append '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6) '(7 8 9))
;=> (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)
```

Now, you're writing your function, and you've said that `level` should return a list.  That means that if `level` has a few different execution paths, each one needs to produce a list. So, let's have a look at your implementation.

```
(define level
  (lambda (L)
    (cond ((null? L) L)
          ((not( pair? L)) L)
          (else (append (level(car L)) (level(cdr L)))))))
```

In the question, you said that you're writing a function that should take a list, so `L` can be one of two things;  it can either be the empty list, or it can be a pair.  At the moment, your `cond` has *three* cases, though.

```
(cond ((null? L) L)                                  ; handle an empty list
      ((not( pair? L)) L)
      (else (append (level(car L)) (level(cdr L))))) ; handle a pair
```

If you're always calling `level` with a list, you don't need the second case.  However, since in the third case, you *do* call `(level (car L))`, and you don't know whether or not whether `(car L)` will be a list, it seems like you *do* eventually call `level` with non-lists.  You need to make a decision about whether, e.g., `(level 'a)` should be legal, and if it should, what it should be.  At the moment, it seems like you're trying to have `(level 'a)` be legal and return `(a)`.  That's fine, but you should specify the contract.  If this is what you want to do, then you do need that second case in your `cond`, but since `(level 'a)` should return `(a)`, you actually need that case to return `(list L)`, not `L`.

The other option here, if you *do* want `level` to be strict, and always require a list as an argument, then you need to add some more logic to determine whether the `(car L)` is a list, and if it is, to recursively call `level` on it, and call `append` with the result. One way to do this would be like this:

```
(define (level L)
  (cond
    ((null? L) L)
    ((pair? L) (append (if (list? (car L))
                           (level (car L))
                           (list L))
                       (level (cdr L))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Append works on lists. If you call `level` with a list `'(1 2 3)` the very first iteration it will do `(append (level '1) (level (cdr '(2 3)))`. Now '1 is no pair thus will evaluate to 1, which is **not** a list. It will be like calling `(append '1 ...)` which is a contract violation.

**EDIT**

Here is a implementation of `flatten` in Pretty Big. This is based on Chris Jester-Young's [answer for a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7324493/1565698). It's more efficient than the `append` versions.

```
(define (flatten lst)
  ;; helper function that accumulates
  (define (reverse-flatten-into x lst)
    (if (pair? x)
        (foldl reverse-flatten-into lst x)
        (cons x lst)))

  (reverse (reverse-flatten-into lst '())))
```

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you define a recursive function, every clause ought to return objects of a similar type.  In your case, the recursive call in the third clause expects a list to be returned (for use by `append`) but the second clause returns an 'atom'.  And thus the compiler/runtime complains with 'expected a list.'

The fix for this is to return `(list L)` in the second `cond` clause.